# Протоколы FTP, SFTP, SSH

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

Прочитав около 5 статей о протоколах передачи файлов на сервер, стало ясно следующее:

**FTP** - простой протокол передачи файлов, без лишнего шифрования и всяческой защиты.
**SFTP** - защищенный протокол передачи файлов, в следствии он более медленный чем FTP.
**SSH** - протокол позволяющий удаленно управлять ОС и передавать файлы.

В своей работе я часто использую ftp, и если нужно удалить папку в которой овер много папок в которых тоже есть папки и т.д., при этом вес главной папки относительно небольшой, то этот процесс занимает достаточно продолжительное время. Так вот, как можно ускорить этот процесс, SSH быстрее FTP? Или есть другие протоколы предназначенные для скоростной передачи?

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп. "Удалить папку, в которой овер много папок" можно одной командой по протоколу удалённого управления, и её обработкой система будет заниматься сама и у себя, удалённо вы быстрее точно не сделаете. "Скоростная передача" тут немного ни при чём.

Comment: По SSH нельзя передавать файлы. Это удаленная консоль. SFTP ничтожно медленнее, чем FTP. Разницу можно проигнорировать

Comment: D-side, т.е. сервер получает 1 команду на удаление конкретной папки и дальше занимается этим автономно, а почему так долго, например если удалить аналогичную папку в windows будет все намного быстрее? Для FTP использую FileZilla и при удалении "папки в которой много папок" в логах вижу что-то следующее: получение списка каталогов -> удаление подпапки -> получение списка каталогов и т.д.

Comment: @Shillkas медленно потому, что протокол ftp был разработан 46 лет назад. ввиду проявившихся сразу и выявленных позже «родовых травм» нынче используется, пожалуй, только особыми извращенцами. под термином sftp обычно подразумевают как минимум два абсолютно разных протокола: «ftp поверх ssl» (со всеми недостатками ftp) и «ssh file transfer protocol», т.е., фактически то же самое, что и термин «ssh» в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov *По SSH нельзя передавать файлы* — ещё как можно. программа scp именно для этого и предназначена. и даже монтировать удалённые файловые системы можно. программа sshfs именно для этого и предназначена.

Comment: SFTP — это и есть расширение ssh для управления файлами, так что последние два пункта — суть одно и тоже. Существует FTPS — расширенный ftp обёрнутый в ssl, но он полузабыт-полупохоронен... Есть ещё FTP-SSH (или как ещё он там называется) — обычный ftp туннелированый через ssh.

Comment: @Shillkas по SSH, не по FTP. По FTP вы не отдаёте машине произвольных команд, вы действуете в рамках протокола FTP, который весьма ограничен (это и хорошо, и плохо -- предоставляемый им доступ более-менее очевиден, но сложные действия им выполнять невозможно). А SSH может вас пустить в шелл, допускающий выполнение любых команд (вопрос только в настройках доступа и типе шелла). И введённые команды будут полностью выполняться на удалённой машине, без участия вашей. Вот.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov игнорируя уже упомянутый `scp`, "удалённой консоли" так-то достаточно для передачи файла. Выполняете на сервере команду `cat файл`, получаете в стандартный вывод содержимое файла, пайпаете в локальный файл, готово. Аналогично в обратную сторону, только пайп будет обратным и вызов `cat` будет другим.